# Concatenate multiple instance of the qualified string

Tags: xslt-1.0

Based on the given xpath below I need to concatenate all of instance that will satisfy on below xpath condition (with space in between string). Thanks in advance.

> ShippingOrder/ShipmentInformation/Instructions[ProprietaryShippingInstructionsCode
>   = 'HTZS08']/notes/FreeFormText

Comment: Please provide an example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: P.S. Why do you not accept answers provided to your other questions?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I forgot about the previous questions that I posted because the requirement changed, I apologize on it Can I just delete those?